# Prevent timeout of HTTP request with long running background work

Tags: node.js, web-services, http, tcp

The following case:

I have a webserver, which downloads files if requested by clients and works as a filecache.

The client requests a file and passes the file url as parameter. The webserver checks, if he has the file cached. If not, the webserver downloads the file and serves the file after downloading.

The response to the client has to be the file. It is not possible to close the response with a "downloading, please check back later" and open a second request from the client after a couple of minutes.
No, I won't switch to sockets, as the client does not support it. The client has to use .NET WebClient.DownloadFile.

The problem is, that the HTTP request to the webserver is on hold while downloading the file. The file can be any size, which results in the client's request canceling with timeout, if the file can't be downloaded and returned to the client in time.

I don't want to set a timeout on the client, as this would be too much of a hack.

Does anybody have an idea how to tackle this problem? I have read about HTTP status 102 (processing), but I have no idea how to set that status.

I am using node.js on the webserver, but interested in any kind of (tcp level) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem streaming the download to a temporary file and serving the content of the file to the requesting clients.

As the file grows while downloading is use npm growing-file to open the temp file and pipe the data into the response stream of the clients.

Comment: and did you have no interest in sharing this code with us?

Comment: No, I don't. I didn't ask for code, I've asked for theoretical input. So in response, I've answered my own question with this concept, which should bring anyone interested a step further.

Comment: Actually this question and answer are completely useless. This is just one more disappointing google result when trying to find the answer someone needs now.

Answer (score 0):

The web server should start delivering the file content to the client as soon as any of it is received from wherever it is downloading it from ... rather than downloading the entire file before it sends any of it to the client, which wastes time and space.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but time and space are not a factor. The files are saved to disc anyway and the clients are in the same network as the filecache, so they are transferred within seconds.

I need a solution that does not require a heavy change on the filecache's code.

Comment: Time is what your question is *about.* If the file is transferred in seconds and time isn't a factor, there is nothing left for your question to be about.